# shopify number of transactions discrepancy with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, shopify

It might be a very stupid rocky question but I’ve never worked with Shopify before.

We have implemented Google Analytics via default functionality available with Shopify Plus. On top of it, I have added quite simple JS to track Consumer Funnel Steps and activated enhanced ecommerce feature.

One month later I have discovered the discrepancy in both number of transactions reported and the revenue that is nearly 50% which clearly indicates that something went wrong. My investigation has shown no patterns from the point of payment method/checkout process/device category.  Our success manager told us that the process looks ok from their end and the issue is on our end.

Please help me to understand where else shall I look to identify the bug. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue for Google Analytics and it happens on all ecommerce platforms and the main reason behind it is **ad blockers**.

About 20% of users use ad blocking extensions which prevents Google Analytics from firing and capturing any data regarding that visit (this also includes ecommerce data), thus, discrepancies are created between the numbers reported in Shopify backend and Google Analytics.

There are more reasons behind why the discrepancies might happen (some of them are of legit concerns like faulty tracking) but ad blocking extensions are probably responsible for most of the discrepancies. If interested, you can see the full list of [transaction discrepancy causes here](https://analyticshelp.io/blog/closer-look-transaction-discrepancy-google-analytics-woocommerce-shopify-data-not-match/).